# Can't ping all the loop back addresses

Tags: linux, networking, ping, loopback

As we know, the range for loopback addresses is 127.0.0.0 – 127.255.255.255.
On my Linux box, I am able to ping all the addresses like 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.254, etc. (i.e., all addresses from 127.0.0.1 through 127.0.0.254). But I am unable to ping other addresses, like 127.0.1.1, etc. (It works on my Windows 10 laptop, though.) Can someone throw some light on this?

Comment: `ip addr show lo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the block 127.0.0.0/8 is reserved for loopback doesn't imply that your machine is configured for the whole block.

For example, on my Linux deskop:

```
root:~# ifconfig |grep '127.'
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
root:~# ping -c 1 127.1.1.1
PING 127.1.1.1 (127.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms

--- 127.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.035/0.035/0.035/0.000 ms
root:~# ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
root:~# ping -c 1 127.1.1.1
PING 127.1.1.1 (127.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 127.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

This depends on the way interface `lo` has been configured, especially for the netmask.

Comment: Thanks a lot binarym. Didn't realize about the netmask. I got it working now.